# Замена перехода каретки на тэг 

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! 
Возникла следующая проблема: масив текста хранится в БД MYSQL переодически он извлекается и модифицируется необходимо заменять символы перехода строки /n /r, на <br>.
Пробывал функцию nl2br. но при сохранении текста несколько раз <br>  дублируются везде.
Подскажите возможные варианты решения спасибо!

Comment: Вы уверены, что в строке "\\n\\r", а не **"\\r\\n"** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "необходимо заменять символы перехода строки /n /r Пробывал функцию nl2br";
echo str_replace('/n /r','<br />',$str);
```

Comment: если в ручную не проставить /n /r не работает

Comment: Может, потому что символ возврата каретки - `\n`, а не `/n`? Плюс может потому, что `'\n'` - два символа, а `"\n"` - один?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такое:

```
$text = str_replace("\n", "\n<br />", (str_replace('<br />', '', $text));
```

То есть мы сперва чистим все теги `<br />`(оставшиеся от предыдущего сохранения), а потом добавляем после каждого переноса.

Comment: Спасибо! 
это рабочий вариант)

Answer (score 0):

При сохранении сохраняйте в таком виде в каком оно есть (заменять \n на <br> не нужно)
При редактировании в textarea выводи тоже так, как есть. А при отображении делайте замену.

Comment: Вообще текст, говорят, лучше хранить в таком виде, чтобы он не требовал обработки при выводе. Ладно простые сайтики, но на каком-нибудь твиттере лишняя функция при выводе сильно повысила бы нагрузку на сервер.

Ну и по хорошему всю нагрузку надо перекидывать на админку, в идеальном случае вывод должен выглядеть как цепочка `query-fetch-echo`.